# Can't crawl RDF Data with Apache Nutch

Tags: web-crawler, rdf, nutch, linked-data

I am trying to Crawl the DBpedia with Apache Nutch 1.15, but i'm having problems with parsing RDF files.

On the parsing phase, i only get this message:

**apache_nutch    | Error parsing: http://dbpedia.org/data/Moscow.xml: failed(2,0): Can't retrieve Tika parser for mime-type application/rdf+xml
**

following this [reference](http://www.treselle.com/blog/apache-nutch-with-customized-mime-type/), i configured my parse-plugins.xml to parse application/rdf+xml as this:

```
<mimeType name="application/rdf+xml">
    <plugin id="parse-tika" />
    <plugin id="feed" />
</mimeType>
```

But still, the message persists.

Even when i use Any23, mapping the parse filter as

```
<alias name="any23-parserFilter"
        extension-id="Any23Parser" />
```

and setting the parsers for the mime type as:

```
<mimeType name="application/rdf+xml">
    <plugin id="parse-tika" />
    <plugin id="feed" />
</mimeType>
```

The message still persists.

What i'm missing here?

Comment: I can't really help here with the Nutch issue, but I'm wondering why do you need to crawl DBpedia?

Comment: @AKSW, i just used DBpedia as an example. I have no intention of crawling since the dumps are available. Actually, i just want to crawl RDF data from other sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nutch [any23 plugin](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.15/org/apache/nutch/any23/package-summary.html) is targeted to embedded RDF (RDFa) and Microdata. Technically, it only implements the HtmlParseFilter which requires that the document is successfully parsed by a Parser implementation.

To extract RDFa, try this and you should see many extracted triples:

```
> bin/nutch parsechecker \
   -Dany23.extractors=html-microdata,html-rdfa11 \
   -Dplugin.includes='protocol-http|parse-html|any23' \
  https://schema.org/NewsArticle
...
Any23-Triples=<https://schema.org/NewsArticle> <http://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa#usesVocabulary> <http://schema.org/> .
...
```